# Resample to Pandas DataFrame to Hourly using Hour as mid-point

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with temperature measurements at a frequency of 5 minutes. I would like to resample this dataset to find the mean temperature per hour.

This is typically done using `df['temps'].resample('H', how='mean')` but this averages all values that fall within the hour - using all times where '12' is the hour, for example. I want something that gets all values from 30 minutes either side of the hour (or times nearest to the actual hour) and finds the mean that way. In other words, for the resampled time step of 1200, use all temperature values from 1130 to 1230 to calculate the mean.

Example code below to create a test data frame:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=200, freq='5min')
temps = pd.Series(range(200), index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['temps'] = temps
```

Can this be done using the built-in `resample` method? I'm sure I've done it before using `pandas` but cannot find any reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
print (df['temps'].shift(freq='30Min').resample('H').mean())
```